# Change terminal cursor position in Rust

Tags: rust

In order to write a game, I need to write some characters at different positions in the terminal. I used

```
println!("{c:>width$}", c="*", width=x);
```

It's almost OK with the `x` position, but I want to change the `y` position, when I press <kbd>space</kbd>. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For terminal control I would recommend using a crate such as [Termion](https://crates.io/crates/termion).  With Termion it looks something like:

```
fn main() {
    let mut stdout = stdout().into_raw_mode().unwrap();

    writeln!(stdout, "{}Placed at 3,7",
       termion::cursor::Goto(3, 7));
}
```

See the [examples](https://github.com/Ticki/termion/tree/master/examples).

Comment: Just a note: this doesn't work on Windows prior to the Anniversary Update (I believe).  If you care about cross-platform support, use something else.

Answer (score 5):

You could also use [ncurses-rs](https://github.com/jeaye/ncurses-rs), which is a thin wrapper around the ncurse library, or [Cursive](https://github.com/gyscos/Cursive), which is a bit higher level and allow you to create various widgets in the Terminal.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [crossterm_cursor](https://crates.io/crates/crossterm_cursor) for this, it provides you a way to deal with cursor movement and a lot of other cross-platform stuff.

```rust
use crossterm::cursor;

let mut cursor = cursor();

/// Moving the cursor
// Set the cursor to position X: 10, Y: 5 in the terminal
cursor.goto(10,5);

// Move the cursor up,right,down,left 3 cells.
cursor.move_up(3);
cursor.move_right(3);
cursor.move_down(3);
cursor.move_left(3);

/// Safe the current cursor position to recall later
// Goto X: 5 Y: 5
cursor.goto(5,5);
// Safe cursor position: X: 5 Y: 5
cursor.save_position();
// Goto X: 5 Y: 20
cursor.goto(5,20);
// Print at X: 5 Y: 20.
print!("Yea!");
// Reset back to X: 5 Y: 5.
cursor.reset_position();
// Print 'Back' at X: 5 Y: 5.
print!("Back");

// hide cursor
cursor.hide();
// show cursor
cursor.show();
// blink or not blinking of the cursor (not widely supported)
cursor.blink(true)
```

You might as well use [crossterm](https://github.com/TimonPost/crossterm) to do this, but that will include non-cursor related functionalities as well. An other possibility is, to use the command [api](https://timonpost.github.io/crossterm/docs//command.html). Please check out the [examples](https://github.com/TimonPost/crossterm/tree/master/examples) for more information about the cursor functionalities.